# How to define a method so that return the instance of the current class not of the class where it was inherited in Python?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, operator-overloading

I am trying Overloading an operator forcing it to return an object of the same instance of the current class not the parent class where the method was overloaded.

```
class Book:
    def __init__(self,name,pages):
        self.name=name
        self.pages=pages

    def __add__(self,other):
        return Book(self.name,(self.pages + other.pages))


class Encyclopedia(Book):
    def __init__(self,name,pages):
        Book.__init__(self,name,pages)


a=Encyclopedia('Omina',234)
b=Encyclopedia('Omnia2',244)
ab=a+b
print ab

Out: <__main__.Book instance at 0x1046dfd88>
```

For instance in this case I would like to return an `Encycolpedia` instance (not a `Book` instance) without overloading another time the operator `__add__` with the same line with  `Encyclopedia` instead of `Book` I have tried:

```
return self(self.name,(self.pages + other.pages))
```

But it doesn't work.

What if the Class Enclcopedia has another attribute:

```
class Encyclopedia(Book):
    def __init__(self,name,pages,color):
        Book.__init__(self,name,pages)
        self.color=color
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could utilize self.__class__ instead of casting to Book. Your original add function should look like:

```
def __add__(self,other):
    return self.__class__(self.name,(self.pages + other.pages))
```

Comment: what if the class Encyclopedia has another attribute?

Comment: @GM Then you will need to override the addition operator within the Encyclopedia class to handle that attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to do it something like this, which overloads the base class's methods (in this case, generally by calling them first and then doing additional processing on the result — although that's not a requirement):

```
class Book(object):
    def __init__(self, name, pages):
        self.name = name
        self.pages = pages

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Book(self.name, self.pages+other.pages)

    def __str__(self):
        classname = self.__class__.__name__
        return '{}({}, {})'.format(classname, self.name, self.pages)

class Encyclopedia(Book):
    def __init__(self, name, pages, color):
        Book.__init__(self, name, pages)
        self.color = color

    def __add__(self, other):
        tmp = super(Encyclopedia, self).__add__(other)
        return Encyclopedia(tmp.name, tmp.pages, self.color+other.color)

    def __str__(self):
        classname = self.__class__.__name__
        return '{}({!r}, {}, {!r})'.format(classname, self.name, self.pages,
                                         self.color)


a = Encyclopedia('Omina', 234, 'grey')
b = Encyclopedia('Omnia2', 244, 'blue')
ab = a+b
print(ab)  # -> Encyclopedia('Omina', 478, 'greyblue')
```

Comment: Thanks martineu but in this way you have overload another time the operator __add__  and I was looking for a solution without repeating the code

Comment: The code does _not_ repeat the code in the base class for the `__add__()` method, it _uses_ it...and then does whatever additional processing is needed to handle the attributes possessed only by the derived class. This is necessary because the base class has no knowledge of the subclass(es) that will be derived from it — and is thus the canonical way to do object-oriented programming.